# Opera Browser (28.0): How can I switch the country-specific default search engine set?

Tags: opera, search-engines

I've recently switched from Firefox to Opera.

Unfortunately, I downloaded and installed it while in Turkey, and now have a set of default search engines suitable for Turkish users.

I've tried reinstalling over-the-top back in the UK, but to no avail - it just doesn't want to (re-)instate the GB collection of search engines.

Is there way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open: "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Local State" file (it's has no extension).
There is following parameter there:

```
"location":{"country":"RU","country_from_server":"RU","timestamp":"1449927204600000000"}
```

Change both parameters according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've fixed, but by rather drastic means. I did a full uninstall of Opera (with [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com), which cleans up the registry and leftover files), and then reinstalled from scratch (download and all).

I would like to have tried a less draconian uninstall first, but I had neither the patience nor the time.

This answer is for the record; if anyone has a better solution, I'd still like to hear it.